# How can I prevent my discord.py Bot from banning me?

Tags: discord.py

I want to find out how to prevent banning me from servers over my Bot, but sadly, I haven't succeded... Does anyone have any solutions?

````py
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, *, member: discord.Member = None, reason=None):
    bot_owner = client.get_user(705557092802625576)
    if member is None:
        embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff2200, title = "Argumente Fehlen",
                              description = f'{ctx.author.mention} Bitte nenne einen User den du Bannen möchtest.\n\n`o?ban [@nutzer / id] [(optional) Grund]`')
        embed.set_author(name = f'{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}',
                         icon_url = f'{ctx.message.author.avatar_url}')
        return await ctx.send(embed = embed)

    elif member.id == bot_owner:
        embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff2200, title = 'Fehler aufgetreten!',
                              description = f'{ctx.author.mention} Ohnezahn DNC#8135 kann nicht gebannt werden!\nGrund: Er ist der Bot-Inhaber',
                              footer = f'User-ID: str(member.id)')
        return await ctx.send(embed = embed)

    elif member.id != bot_owner:

        await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason = reason)
        embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff2200, title = ":hammer: Bannhammer wurde geschwungen!",
                              description = 'Gebannt von:' f'{ctx.author.mention} / {ctx.author.id} / {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}\n\nNutzer: {member.name}#{member.discriminator} / {member.id} / {member.mention}\nGrund des Banns: **```py\n{reason}\n```**')
        embed.set_author(name = f'{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}',
                         icon_url = f'{ctx.message.author.avatar_url}')
        embed.set_footer(text = 'User-ID: ' + str(member.id))
    return await ctx.send(embed = embed)
````

Comment: Do you want to be unbannable on all servers your bot is on? (*At least that your own bot can not ban you*)

Comment: Exactly, that's my goal

Comment: Why do you have {} around `user.id`? Simply write `elif user.id != 705557092802625576:`, assuming that thats your user id

Comment: 705557092802625576 is indeed my user id lol

Answer (score 1):

Using `get_user` required the user to be cashed you can make a `fetch_user` request but actually you don't need that you only have to compare the id like this.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if member.id == 1234:
        return await ctx.send('Can not ban owner')


    # code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your code a bit above and shown it with an `if` and `else` example, of course you can always adjust it at the end.

You can use the built in function `client.owner_id` once and then compare it with `member`, but you can also do it a bit different.
For this we first **define a user** that you don't want to be banned by your own bot:

```py
bot_owner = client.get_user(YourID)
```

Then we compare the `member` object with this ID and don't let the user be banned if `bot_owner` matches `member`:

```py
    if member == bot_owner: # Or member.id
        return await ctx.send("You can't ban the bot owner")
```

Of course, the other case would then be that the user is banned.

**One possible code would be:**

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    bot_owner = client.get_user(YourID)
    if member == bot_owner: # Or member.id
        return await ctx.send("You can't ban the bot owner")
    else:
        await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f"{member} got banned. Reason: {reason}")
```

Comment: Okay, I tried the code you provided and it still banned me...

Comment: I changed it a little so it's in an embed.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/856891800845418520/860103231031345162/unknown.png

Comment: Does not ban me though. Have you inserted the correct ID? Can you edit your question with the new code?

Comment: Yes, I edited the code provided in the question

Comment: @OhnezahnDNC Have you tried to remove `elif` and replace it with `if`? Also maybe try to compare `member.id` instead of just `member`, edited my question for that.

Comment: @OhnezahnDNC "*Member 705557092802625576 Test not found*" What is that for a traceback?

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/823168666237534248/860119400488894464/unknown.png

Comment: @OhnezahnDNC `*` is inserted wrongly in your code... It has to stand after the `member` argument.